# Failure to parse this json field

Tags: java, json

I can get other fields correctly, but can parse the "title" or "title_full" values. I always receives an empty string. I am using the org.json library. This is the json. What's the trick?

```
try {
                title = jsonDoc.getString("title_full");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                log.info("no full title: " + docString);
            }

{
  "organizations": [],
  "uuid": "d0adc516c9012113774557365f9847da99b228e7",
  "thread": {
    "site_full": "www.fark.com",
    "main_image": "http://img.fark.net/images/cache/orig/5/51/fark_514Jh7VFpynQw4MyN2xcK1jwCxk.png?t=RQrnhq8EGZiUuElMitgLOQ&amp;f=1488776400",
    "site_section": "http://www.fark.com/discussion/",
    "section_title": "FARK.com: Discussion links",
    "url": "http://www.fark.com/comments/9500577/I-want-to-support-work-that-NY-Times-Washington-Post-are-doing-I-can-only-afford-one-subscription-Who-do-you-recommend-I-throw-my-support-to?cpp=1",
    "country": "US",
    "domain_rank": 3382,
    "title": "(9500577) I want to support the work that the NY Times and Washington Post are doing. I can only afford one subscription. Who do you recommend I throw my support to?",
    "performance_score": 0,
    "site": "fark.com",
    "participants_count": 31,
    "title_full": "FARK.com: (9500577) I want to support the work that the NY Times and Washington Post are doing. I can only afford one subscription. Who do you recommend I throw my support to?",
    "spam_score": 0.0,
    "site_type": "discussions",
    "published": "2017-03-03T12:00:00.000+02:00",
    "replies_count": 2,
    "uuid": "67213179a24931106e75cd588386bd30fb3bbdc8"
  },
  "author": "EbolaNYC",
  "url": "http://www.fark.com/comments/9500577/I-want-to-support-work-that-NY-Times-Washington-Post-are-doing-I-can-only-afford-one-subscription-Who-do-you-recommend-I-throw-my-support-to?cpp=1#c107765048",
  "ord_in_thread": 1,
  "title": "",
  "locations": [], 
  "entities": {
    "persons": [],
    "locations": [],
    "organizations": []
  },
  "highlightText": "",
  "language": "english",
  "persons": [], 
  "text": "dionysusaur : Either the NY Post or the WA Times.\nOnly asshats read the NY Post.",
  "external_links": [],
  "published": "2017-03-03T15:58:00.000+02:00",
  "crawled": "2017-03-03T17:05:26.049+02:00", 
  "highlightTitle": "",
  "social": {
    "gplus": {"shares": 0}, 
    "pinterest": {"shares": 0}, 
    "vk": {"shares": 0}, 
    "linkedin": {"shares": 0},
    "facebook": {"likes": 0, "shares": 0, "comments": 0}, 
    "stumbledupon": {"shares": 0}
   }
}
```

Comment: COuld you indent the json ? It would be simpler to analyse the structure.

Comment: You have to access the nested datastructure, title and full_title are not on the first level, you have to traverse the nesting.

Comment: See, with the indentation this is clear that the problem is there is no `title` or `title_full`  in your `jsonDoc`, they are in the `thread` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I formatted the json code, the problem becomes obvious:
`title_full` is only available inside the `thread` node, and a non-empty `title` is also only inside the `thread` node. So you'll first have to access the `thread` node and then access `title` and `title_full` inside that node.

Using the org.json library, you can access the fields like this:

```
String fullTitle = jsonDoc.getJSONObject("thread").getString("title_full");
```

Comment: try ``jsonDoc.getJSONObject("thread").getString("title_full")``

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON seems like follows:

```
{
     {
    "main": {
        "key": "value",
            },
    },
}
```

So, First fetch the main json and then the key.

Code should be like as follows:

```
String something = jsonDoc.get("main").get("key").toString();
```

There are two title values in your JSON, Do check which title you need before fetching.

Comment: This is for me the most complete/well formated answer. You should just add some precision about what `jsonDoc.get("main")` will return. And what is actually `jsonDoc` as those will be the same type of strucutre.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the json you will see that the "title" and "title_full" fields are in the thread field.
So try reading that field and then parsing the filed into a new jsonObject and you should be able to get them.